# Date Formatter NOT Reflecting Proper String if Time Difference is in Seconds

Tags: java, date, datetime, time

I have a scenario, where I need to save the packet received time, at some time interval. The interval is in seconds or minutes. (Less time gap).

Here is my simple Test class, where I'm providing 60 seconds interval time for the next Packet.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date currDate = new Date();
        Date nextPointDate = new Date(currDate.getTime() + 60 * 1000);

        System.out.println(currDate + "  " + nextPointDate);

        System.out.println(DateUtil.getFormattedDate(currDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        + ", " + DateUtil.getFormattedDate(nextPointDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }
```

here is my Date Util method which is called here :

```
public static String getFormattedDate(Date date, String pattern) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    return dateFormat.format(new Date());
}
```

and I got the output as below:

```
Tue Mar 19 14:57:50 IST 2019  Tue Mar 19 14:58:50 IST 2019
2019-03-19 14:57:50, 2019-03-19 14:57:50
```

The first line of output is correct and showing me 1 min difference, But
The second line of output is still the same string for both.

What's the reason behind it. How can I achieve the expected output?

Comment: What is `DateUtil` here? (And are you in a position where you could use `java.time` instead of the `java.util.Date` API? `java.time` is *much* cleaner.)

Comment: Sorry @JonSkeet, I just missed the method.

Comment: side note:  Date class is outdated use modern class LocalDate

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Turn on the warnings in your IDE. Then it should warn you that `date` in an unused parameter in `getFormattedDate`. I hope that that will give you a hint to what is wrong. Your IDE and its warnings can be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, your `return dateFormat.format(new Date());` cause the issue :/

Your correct implementation should be  `return dateFormat.format(date);`

Comment: Aah, How can I not see this. Thanks @Manh.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `Date` in `DateUtil`!

```
public static String getFormattedDate(Date date, String pattern) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    return dateFormat.format(new Date()); // change it to the date passed in!
}
```